# the common Limit of two adjacent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a question concerning a sequence problem I encountered:
With their first terms being a and b respectively and defined as not equal:
$$ u_{n+1} = \frac{u_n+λv_n}{1+λ}$$ and
$$ v_{n+1} = \frac{u_n+μv_n}{1+μ}\ $$
With $ λ> μ> 0$

We need to Show That Un and Vn are adjacent and find their common limit, proving they’re adjacent is the easy part:

For n>1

$$ dn= v_{n+1} - u_{n+1}= -( \frac{u_n+λv_n}{1+λ}\ - \frac{u_n+μv_n}{1+μ}) $$

$$ = \frac{(u_n+μv_n)(1+λ)-(u_n+λv_n)(1+μ)}{(1+μ)(1+λ)} $$

$$=\frac{(u_n+λv_n+μu_n+λμv_n)-(u_n+μv_n+λu_n+λμv_n)}{(1+μ)(1+λ)} =\frac{(λ-μ)(v_n-u_n)}{(1+μ)(1+λ)}$$

Since the difference is bigger than zero and a geometric series with r<1 we have vn>un and the fact that their differences converge to 0

Moreover
$$ u_{n+1}-u_n  = \frac{-λu_n+λv_n}{1+λ}\ =\frac {λd_n}{1+λ} > 0 $$
$$ v_{n+1}- v_n= \frac{u_n-v_n}{1+μ}=\frac{-d_n}{1+μ} < 0  $$

With that we have proven adjacency.  however, no method I use seems to able to lead me anywhere closer to the common limit.

Comment: Please edit your posting to correct your MathJax typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your computations, you've got :
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb N, \ d_n = \alpha^n (b-a),$$
with $\alpha$ beeing the constant that you computed when computing $d_{n+1}$. However,
$$u_{n+1} - u_n = \frac{\lambda d_n}{1+\lambda} = \frac{\lambda(b-a)}{1+\lambda} \alpha^n =: \beta \alpha^n.$$
So when summing on each side from $k=0$ to $k=n-1$,
$$ u_n - u_0 = \beta \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha^k.$$
Thus, when $n$ goes to $+\infty$ if $\ell$ is the limit of the sequence $(u_n)$,
$$\ell = a + \frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}.$$
I leave it to you to replace $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by their expressions in terms of $a, b, \lambda$ and $\mu$. The trick that consists of computing the value of the series of general term $u_{n+1} - u_n$ to compute the limit of $u_n$ is often very useful, especially when dealing whith sequences defined by induction.

Comment: That's it! thank you, friend, using the property of geometric series came flying past my mind, but never pursued it.